# cakephp ajax not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I've 2 ajax form in my ctp,
One is working and other is not,instead it gets redirected.

This is my .ctp file

```
<div>
            <?php  echo $ajax->form('deletecreativeschedule','post',array('id'=>'delete','model'=>'admin','update'=>'myTable')); ?>                
            <input type="hidden" id="deviceid" name="deviceid" value="<?php echo $device['Device']['id'] ?>" />
             <input type="hidden" name="scheduleid" id="scheduleid"/>
             <input name="btnDelete" type="image" src="/<?php echo $site_root ?>/img/btnDelete.gif" height="16" class="sbtnDelete"  id="sbtnDelete" onclick="return deleteSchedule();"  title="Delete creative" >
            <?php echo $form->end(); ?>

            <br>
            <?php  echo $ajax->form('swapcreativeschedule','post',array('id'=>'swap','controller'=>'admin','update'=>'myTable')); ?>                
            <input type="hidden" id="deviceid" name="deviceid" value="<?php echo $device['Device']['id'] ?>" />                 
             <input type="hidden" name="aIdAjax" id="aIdAjax"/>
             <input type="hidden" name="aSeqAjax" id="aSeqAjax"/>


           <input name="btnUP" type="image" src="/<?php echo $site_root ?>/img/up.png" class="sbtnup"  id="sbtnup" onclick="return SwapRow('0');"  title="Delete creative" >
            <input name="btnDown" type="image" src="/<?php echo $site_root ?>/img/down.png" class="sbtndown"  id="sbtnup" onclick="return SwapRow('1');"  title="Delete creative" >
            <?php echo $form->end(); ?>
```

and in controller:

```
function deletecreativeschedule()
{
$this->autorender = false;
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
function swapcreativeschedule()
{
$this->autorender = false;
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

and in views/admin folder i've created files deletecreativeschedule.ctp and swapcreativeschedule.ctp

ajax is working fine for deleteschedule
but for swapcreativeschedule it is redirecting to /admin/swapcreativeschedule

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it'll work,

```
  <?php  echo $form->create('deletecreativeschedule'); ?>                
        <input type="hidden" id="deviceid" name="deviceid" value="<?php echo $device['Device']['id'] ?>" />
         <input type="hidden" name="scheduleid" id="scheduleid"/>
         <input name="btnDelete" type="image" src="/<?php echo $site_root ?>/img/btnDelete.gif" height="16" class="sbtnDelete"  id="sbtnDelete" onclick="return deleteSchedule();"  title="Delete creative" >
         <? echo $ajax->submit('btnDelete.gif',array("url"=>array('controller'=>'your controller','action'=>'ur action',$device['Device']['id']),'class'=>'sbtnDelete','update'=>'ur updateDiv') ?>
<?php echo $form->end(); ?>


<br>
 <?php  echo $form->create('swapcreativeschedule'); ?>                
        <input type="hidden" id="deviceid" name="deviceid" value="<?php echo $device['Device']['id'] ?>" />                 
         <input type="hidden" name="aIdAjax" id="aIdAjax"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="aSeqAjax" id="aSeqAjax"/>

<? echo $ajax->submit('up.png',array("url"=>array('controller'=>'your controller','action'=>'ur action',$device['Device']['id']),'class'=>'sbtnup','update'=>'ur updateDiv') ?>
<? echo $ajax->submit('down.png',array("url"=>array('controller'=>'your controller','action'=>'ur action',$device['Device']['id']),'class'=>'sbtndown','update'=>'ur updateDiv') ?>

 <?php echo $form->end(); ?>
```

Comment: in ur controller replace it $this->autoRender = false;$this->layout = NULL;

Comment: this code: echo $form->create('swapcreativeschedule'); echo $ajax->submit('up.png',array("url"=>'admin/swapcreativeschedule', 'onclick'=> 'return SwapRow(0);','class'=>'sbtnup','update'=>'myTable')); makes change in form action as : <form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" id="swapcreativescheduleAddcreativescheduleForm" action="/TMC1/swapcreativeschedules/addcreativeschedule">, why is it so?

Comment: now, ajax is working fine except, after swapcreativeschedule, myTable div gets blank, although $this->autoRender = false;$this->layout = 'ajax'; and there is file in admin folder swapcreativeschedule.ctp

Comment: noap, I put $ajax->form only for both delete and swap, but now div is not updating for swap action

Comment: put in swap  action $this->render('ur ctp path');

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3243/discussion-between-chetan-patel-and-vibha)